# MPMoviePlayerViewController overlay controls NOT responding to touches after reuse

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

This is driving me crazy.

It's simple, I have a MPMoviePlayerViewController and want to display a movie fullscreen. 
Using ARC over iOS 5.0+ I want to make this player app-wide reusable.

The first time the movie plays, it covers the whole screen and plays amazing. Overlay controls shows correctly and reacts to touches fine. I present it using

```
[theMovie.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL];
[theMovie.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

[self presentViewController:theMovie animated:YES completion:^{
    [theMovie.moviePlayer play];
}];
```

After it finishes playing I intercept the notification and run this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [theMovie.moviePlayer stop];
            [theMovie.moviePlayer setContentURL:nil];
}];
```

Now, the issue is that from the second time and on when a movie is played, it show the controls *but* the player doesn't respond to touches anymore in the movie area. I am able to use the controls, back, play/pause, seek, done, etc... but can't touch in a non-control area to toggle the controls visibility. It auto-hides if I let it plays normally, but won't appear again after touching the non-control area.

I have no idea what's going on here. Would love if you could help me.

Thanks,
g.

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of MPMoviePlayerViewController to the .h file, and in m file viewDidLoad  or maybe viewWillAppear just alloc it and init :)